# ReactJS, how to force synchronization when logging in a user and get info from the API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

I am trying to force these two functions to be synchronized and run one after the other before running console.log(user) and setLogin. Essentially I just want all this information to be called form the API and sitting in the user context before the setLogin(); function is activated as some of this information needs to be available or the landing page will not load correctly and causes and error. Is there a way to do this?

```
const Login = (details) => {
        if (details.email === "") return alert("No email entered");
        if (details.password === "") return alert("No password entered");
        if (details.role === "") return alert("Please select a role");

        //call API here to check username and save JWT
        i_sAccessToken(details).then((result) => {
            if (result.detail === "Incorrect email or password") {
                alert("Incorrect email or password");
            } else {
                //if result does not return error set cookie
                Cookie.set("JWT", result.access_token);
                //get USER info from API
                i_sGetLoggedInUser().then((result) => {
                    userUpdate({
                        ...user,
                        email: result.email,
                        name: result.name,
                        id: result.id,
                        role: details.role,
                    });
                });
                i_sGETOrgs().then((result) => {
                    userUpdate({
                        ...user,
                        orgs: result,
                        orgDefault: result[0],
                        orgCurrent: result[0],
                    });
                });
                console.log(user);
                setLogin();
            }
        });
        //get user organisations ------ NEED GET CURRENT ORG API CALL SO DEFAULT ISN'T 0 ------=
    };
```

The API calls look like this...

```
export const i_sAccessToken = async (userDetails) => {
    const reqBody =
        "username=" +
        userDetails.email +
        "&password=" +
        userDetails.password +
        "&grant_type=password";

    try {
        const response = await fetch(
            process.env.REACT_APP_APIADDRESS + "/api/v1/login/access-token",
            {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                },
                body: reqBody,
            }
        );
        const result = await response.json();
        return result;
    } catch (error) {
        APIErrorHandler(error);
    }
};

export const i_sGETOrgs = async () => {
    const Cookie = new Cookies();
    try {
        const response = await fetch(
            process.env.REACT_APP_APIADDRESS + "/api/v1/organizations/",
            {
                method: "GET",
                headers: {
                    Authorization: "Bearer " + Cookie.get("JWT"),
                },
            }
        );
        const result = await response.json();
        return result;
    } catch (error) {
        APIErrorHandler(error);
    }
};
```

user context...

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useContext } from "react";

const UserContext = createContext();
const UpdateUserContext = createContext();

export const useUser = () => {
    return useContext(UserContext);
};

export const useUserUpdate = () => {
    return useContext(UpdateUserContext);
};

export const UserContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState({
        email: "",
        name: "",
        id: "",
        role: "",
        orgs: [],
        orgCurrent: {},
        orgDefault: {},
    });

    const updateUser = (user) => {
        setUser(user);
    };

    return (
        <UserContext.Provider value={user}>
            <UpdateUserContext.Provider value={updateUser}>
                {children}
            </UpdateUserContext.Provider>
        </UserContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated :)

Thanks,

Greg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy man, you need to use async/await for it, something like that:

```js
const Login = async (details) => {
  if (details.email === "") return alert("No email entered");
  if (details.password === "") return alert("No password entered");
  if (details.role === "") return alert("Please select a role");

  //call API here to check username and save JWT
  let result = await i_sAccessToken(details)
  if (result.detail === "Incorrect email or password") {
    alert("Incorrect email or password");
  } else {
    //if result does not return error set cookie
    Cookie.set("JWT", result.access_token);

    //get USER info from API
    let loggedResult = await i_sGetLoggedInUser()
    let orgsResult  = await i_sGETOrgs() 

    let obj = {
      ...user,
      email: loggedResult.email,
      name: loggedResult.name,
      id: loggedResult.id,
      role: details.role,
      orgs: orgsResult,
      orgDefault: orgsResult[0],
      orgCurrent: orgsResult[0],
    };

    userUpdate(obj);
    console.log(obj);

    setLogin();
  }

  //get user organisations ------ NEED GET CURRENT ORG API CALL SO DEFAULT ISN'T 0 ------=
};
```